# How to share a web page (asp.net) with others

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

Here is what I'm trying to do :

The user accesses a web page (asp.net web application), makes his selections and applies filters to render the screen. Now I'm looking for a way to share this view with somebody else who also has access to the application.

Although in a simple scenario this can achieved through query strings and sharing the URL, how can this be achieved in a more complicated scenario where a bunch of selections / filters are applied to render a view ?

To start with, I implemented a basic framework. A datastructure will hold key value pairs which represents the controls and the values associated with it. I persist this to a database and the page will be responsible to parse the key-value collection and render itself but I think this may not be practical when there are complex  controls like a grid with features such as grouping, filtering etc.

Most importantly, it would be great if the solution does'nt force the aspx to be implemented in a certain way for them to be persisted.

Any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use static variables. What is static, that is shared.

Simply said: Static variabels belong to the **application**. All open windows belong to the same application and this should work with the standard settings.

Note that on big web servers IIS can be setup to run multiple instances of the same application. In that case static variables aren't shared so simply. But I think this is a special case and you can omit it.

Comment: Note that any data in static variables will go away when the application stops/restarts. This would happen when you restart the website in IIS, among other things. Don't rely on it if you need to persist data, but it could work if you want two users to see the same thing at the same time.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that what iam looking for.

Comment: Not a great idea. Basically everyone in the system shares the same view and if more than one person is changing the view at the same time, you've got a "Last in wins" situation, and if you read the variable multiple times while rehydrating the view, you could get mixes results as the static variable changes underneath of you.

Comment: Greg, you should use synchronization like Monitor locks etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just brainstorming but here goes...
Since you are storing the controls and their data (basically a customized viewstate) in key-value pairs, and storing that information in the database, associate a key on that state information.  Then just append that key to the query string and when a user comes to that page look up that key in your data base and load the controls with the data that was saved for them, for that key and ... profit?

so your link would look like:
http://www.mysite.com/mypage?id=SomeKey

Without knowing the true intent and the complexity involved this might seem overly simplistic, and apologize if i missed the mark on this completely.

Comment: thanks, i already thought abt that. but again as I was mentioning , the difficult part is loading the page with all the bunch of things. E.g: persisting the tab index and then state of complex controls within that tab such as grid, listview etc which have been sorted, filtered, grouped and may be at a specific page number. So I'm also thinking interms of leaning towards saving the raw html. I'm sorry , even I am just thinking about this loud, not sure if I am giving enough direction to come up with ideas. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is using web parts.  This way the state and data of a particular web part is saved back to the db in a serialized format so that all the controls and data are able to be replayed the way someone last left it.  However this introduces several complexities such as who can edit the web part and who can view it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 3rd party Grid control, they probably store this filter state in a cookie.  You might be able to plug into this system to persist the state for the grid as a special case.  Something like 1) store data from grid's response cookie in database 2) retrieve cookie info from database, add it to response cookie collection.

Comment: Thanks, I was about to bring up this point. Every third party control might have its own way of peristing information which gets tricky again.

Comment: I'm looking into this article :

Comment: Sorry about the earlier post. I'm looking into this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/persistentstatepage.aspx  Another way to state my question is what does it take to reconstruct the entire asp page. Snippet from the article - "This means that the ViewState, the PostData, and the QueryString must all be stored to be able to reconstruct the state completely."  Is that enough ? But I guess third party controls might be an exception.

Comment: That' a tough problem, but it seems like that article is your best bet. Yeah, you might need to deal with 3rd party controls separately: there's no telling if they store the state in the ViewState or not.  You should post your final solution as an answer for posterity sake.